# How to count number of times team is highest scorer in a game from a MySQL cross table?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a MySQL database for quiz bowl.  The design is to have a cross table containing all game results, the cross table having the form:

```
CREATE TABLE game_results(
  id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  game_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
  team_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  score MEDIUMINT);
```

My question is how does one count the number of wins a team has (that is, the number of times a team is the highest scoring team in a particular game) from the table `game_results` using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS wins FROM game_results AS gr1
LEFT JOIN game_results AS gr2 ON gr1.game_id=gr2.game_id AND gr2.team_id != 1234
WHERE gr1.team_id = 1234 AND gr1.score > gr2.score
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT old.team_id,
       COUNT(old.team_id) AS Wins,
       old.game_id
FROM game_results AS old,
  (SELECT MAX(score) AS score,
          game_id
   FROM game_results
   GROUP BY game_id) AS nt
WHERE old.score = nt.score
  AND old.game_id = nt.game_id
GROUP BY old.team_id
```

**EDIT** : Ignore draw games

```
SELECT old.team_id,
       COUNT(old.team_id) AS Wins,
       old.game_id
FROM game_results AS old,
  (SELECT MAX(score) AS score,
          game_id
   FROM game_results
   GROUP BY game_id) AS nt
WHERE old.score = nt.score
  AND old.game_id = nt.game_id
  AND old.game_id NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.game_id
     FROM game_results AS a,
          game_results AS b
     WHERE a.game_id = b.game_id
       AND a.score = b.score
       AND a.id != b.id)
GROUP BY old.team_id
```